# Insert the AVG of a student's grade into another table's attribute called final grade

Tags: database, oracle, procedure

I created this DB:

```
create table student(
student_cod int primary key,
name varchar(30),
birth_date date);

create table course(
code_c int primary key,
description_c varchar(200));

create table discipline(
coddisc int primary key,
description_d varchar(200),
credits int,
course_code int,
constraint fk_coursecode foreign key (course_code) references course (code_c));

create table registration(
student_code int,
code_disc int,
date date,
grade1 number(3,1),
grade2 number(3,1),
grade3 number(3,1),
constraint fk_student foreign key (student_code) references student (student_cod),
constraint fk_coddisc foreign key (cod_disc) references discipline (coddisc));

create table history(
semester int,
final_grade number(3,1),
cod_student int,
cod_dis int,
constraint fk_codal foreign key (cod_student) references student (student_cod),
constraint fk_coddi foreign key (cod_dis) references discipline (coddisc));

insert into student values ​​(01, 'John', to_date('07/04/1998', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
insert into student values ​​(02, 'Anna', to_date('07/03/2000', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
insert into student values ​​(03, 'Marck', to_date('05/12/1995', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));

insert into course values ​​(01, 'Computer Science');

insert into discipline values ​​(01, 'Algorithms 1', 4, 1);

insert into registration values ​​(01, 01, to_date('08/01/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 9.3, 10.0, 8.8);
insert into registration values ​​(02, 01, to_date('07/01/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 8.7, 7.5, 10.0);
insert into registration values ​​(03, 01, to_date('09/01/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 10.0, 10.0, 9.5);

insert into history values ​​(01, 0.0, 01, 01);
insert into history values ​​(01, 0.0, 02, 01);
insert into history values ​​(01, 0.0, 03, 01);
```

I would like to know how to take the average of the 3 grades of a student and insert this value into the final grade that is in the history table using a procedure. I will obviously have to update it, and I tried creating a procedure for it, but it did't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of needing a procedure, you can update the `HISTORY` table using a single update statement.

```sql
UPDATE history h
   SET h.final_grade =
           (SELECT (r.grade1 + r.grade2 + r.grade3) / 3
              FROM registration r
             WHERE r.student_code = h.cod_student AND r.code_disc = h.cod_dis);
```

Once to have multiple semesters in your `HISTORY` table, you will need some way to link the `REG_DATE` in your `REGISTRATION` table to the `SEMESTER` column in your `HISTORY` table

Comment: You mean, that I would need to add `where course, history, registration r, discipline`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean `{where course, history, registration r, discipline}`

Comment: Btw do you know how I can discover if the student is already an adult based on his birth date(using oracle, ofcourse)?

Comment: You can use a query like this to determine the student's age: `SELECT birth_date, TRUNC (MONTHS_BETWEEN (SYSDATE, birth_date) / 12) AS age FROM student;`

Comment: I tried comparing the "age" to see if it was >= 18, but it messaged me saying that age is an invalid identifier. Why is that?

Comment: _"age is an invalid identifier. Why is that? "_  Who knows?  You haven't shown the code.

Comment: As an aside, I see these problems with your "design".  1) In table REGISTRATION, you have a column named DATE of type DATE.  'DATE' is a reserved word .. you can't have a column with that name.  2) I'd expect 'credits' to be associate with 'course', not 'discipline'.  But then I can't really imagine what purpose the DISCIPLINE table really serves.

Comment: I'm not really using the date as date, cuz my language it's different. It's called "data", but it's working fine tho. I managed to make it return me the adult students